# How to change React text area value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a list that takes values from server and i want that whenever an item of the list gets clicked it will change a textarea text to the appropriate variable on the list,

I am getting the user using redux:

```
function ProfilePage() {

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const authObj = useSelector(state => state.auth);

const { user, token, expiredAt } = authObj;
```

I am generating the list like this:

```
 <ul className="SentencesList">

                                                {
                                                      user.approvedPatterns.map((el, i) => (
                                        
                                                        <div key={i}>
                                                            <li>{el.name || ''}</li>
                                                            <hr className="profilePageSentenceListHr" />

                                                        </div>
                                                    ))
                                                }
                                               


                                            </ul>
```

And what i want is that when a li on the list get clicked i will take the appropriate value in the JSON object and show i

```
<textarea  rows="5" cols="60" className="centerPageLargeInputBox" type="text" />
```

The JSON list looks like that:

```
const userList = [
{
    _id: "1",
    username: "****",
    password: "*",
    approvedPatterns:[
      {
        "name":"title 1",
        "text":"some text"
      },
      {
        "name":"title 2",
        "text":"some text1"
      },
      {
        "name":"title 3",
        "text":"some text 2"
      }
    ]
}
```

]

How can i accomplish that?
I am really lost.

Answer (score 2):

I have created the demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f5q3n8?file=src/App.js

So when anyone clicks on the li, the textarea will show the value of that li's text property.